# Ask for PC reboot after both installation and un installation Win8.1of an installer created from Installshield:

Tags: installshield, restart

I am working on Install shield 2013 in Windows 8.1 I have created an installer, Now I need a pop up which will ask for restarting the PC after the installers installation and uninstallation completes. Now I am getting either one. I know how to do a restart pop up after installation. But I want to restart pop up after both. How can i solve this issue.?

Please help. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield should let you add a ScheduleReboot (case sensitive) action to your setup, in the InstallExecuteSequence.